# Does knowledgelake store documents locally before sending to Sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, document-library

I am using KnowledgeLake to scan and store documents in a SharePoint document library. So what happened is the connection between KnowledgeLake and SharePoint got disconnected so it was unable to save a lot of documents to library.
Is there any way I can see those documents in KnowledgeLake which were not uploaded to SharePoint library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be under c:/Users//Roaming/KnowledgeLake/*. You should be able to see each document as a folder and the actual document inside that library. It should be in batch form if you are using Capture.